# Multiple Dropzone.js buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I could have an infinite number of upload buttons (one on each table row) that are a trigger to upload a file using dropzone.js.

If I initialise the dropzone the jQuery way it, I can upload a file on each button, but I'm not sure how to access each event callback?

```
var dropzone = $('.btn-upload').dropzone({
        url: '/api/?action=upload',
        uploadMultiple: false,
        createImageThumbnails: false,
        acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
        autoProcessQueue: true,
        previewTemplate: '<div class="dz-preview dz-file-preview"/>'
    });

dropzone.on('success', function(file, xhr, formData) {
    console.log('done');
});

dropzone.on('error', function(file, errorMessage, xhr) {
    console.log('error');
});
```

If I do it this way, the event callbacks work but I can only upload from the first button:

```
var dropzone = new Dropzone ('.btn-upload', {
        url: '/api/?action=upload',
        uploadMultiple: false,
        createImageThumbnails: false,
        acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
        autoProcessQueue: true,
        previewTemplate: '<div class="dz-preview dz-file-preview"/>'
    });

dropzone.on('success', function(file, xhr, formData) {
    console.log('done');
});

dropzone.on('error', function(file, errorMessage, xhr) {
    console.log('error');
});
```

How can I add an infinite number of instances and access the event callbacks?

Answer (score 2):

For reference, here is the HTML and CSS that I used to test with (CSS and JavaScript are included with the HTML for convenience):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <style>
      .dropzone {
        border: 2px dashed #428BCA;
        border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        padding: 5px;
      }

      .dropzone.dz-clickable { cursor: pointer; }
      .dropzone.dz-clickable * { cursor: default; }
      .dropzone.dz-clickable .dz-message, .dropzone.dz-clickable .dz-message * { cursor: pointer; }
      .dropzone.dz-started .dz-message { display: none; }
      .dropzone.dz-drag-hover { border-style: solid; }
      .dropzone.dz-drag-hover .dz-message { opacity: 0.5; }

      .dropzone .dz-message {
        color: #666;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        margin: 0.2em 0;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .dropzone-previews { display: none !important; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Item</th>
          <th>Result</th>
          <th>Drop Zone</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Item 1</td>
          <td class="js-result"></td>
          <td>
            <form action="/api/?action=upload" method="post" class="dropzone dz-clickable" id="item-1-dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1" />
              <div class="dz-message">Drop here</div>
            </form>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Item 2</td>
          <td class="js-result"></td>
          <td>
            <form action="/api/?action=upload" method="post" class="dropzone dz-clickable" id="item-2-dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <input type="hidden" name="id" value="2" />
              <div class="dz-message">Drop here</div>
            </form>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Item 3</td>
          <td class="js-result"></td>
          <td>
            <form action="/api/?action=upload" method="post" class="dropzone dz-clickable" id="item-3-dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <input type="hidden" name="id" value="3" />
              <div class="dz-message">Drop here</div>
            </form>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="dropzone-previews"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.2.0/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      // turn off DropZone's auto discovery feature
      Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

      $(document).ready(function () {
        /* JavaScript discussed below goes here */
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Two key things to note:

1. The element `<div class="dropzone-previews"></div>` seems to **need** to be present, but I hide it with CSS since I don't need it.
2. I turn off Dropzone's auto discovery feature since I'm going to define and customize the individual drop zones.

To define the drop zones, I found two different methods that work. The first is not ideal since the question indicated the potential for an "infinite number of upload buttons" but it helps to answer the question of how to access the callbacks for multiple drop zones on a single page.

### First solution, define each drop zone using an ID

```
$("form#item-1-dropzone").dropzone({
  url: $("form").attr("action"),
  previewsContainer: ".dropzone-previews",
  init: function () {
    this.on("success", function (file, response, event) {
      var $preview = $(file.previewElement).find("img");
      $("form#item-1-dropzone").closest("tr").find(".js-result").html($preview);
    });

    this.on("error", function (file, errorMessage, xhr) {
      console.error("Dropzone 1 Error");
    });
  }
});

$("form#item-2-dropzone").dropzone({
  url: $("form").attr("action"),
  previewsContainer: ".dropzone-previews",
  init: function () {
    this.on("success", function (file, response, event) {
      var $preview = $(file.previewElement).find("img");
      $("form#item-2-dropzone").closest("tr").find(".js-result").html($preview);
    });

    this.on("error", function (file, errorMessage, xhr) {
      console.error("Dropzone 2 Error");
    });
  }
});

$("form#item-3-dropzone").dropzone({
  url: $("form").attr("action"),
  previewsContainer: ".dropzone-previews",
  init: function () {
    this.on("success", function (file, response, event) {
      var $preview = $(file.previewElement).find("img");
      $("form#item-3-dropzone").closest("tr").find(".js-result").html($preview);
    });

    this.on("error", function (file, errorMessage, xhr) {
      console.error("Dropzone 3 Error");
    });
  }
});
```

Each drop zone is defined based on the form's unique ID attribute which allows me to control which table cell is updated on a successful upload.

**Note:** for testing I used images and since Dropzone generates a preview of the image, I was able to just grab that and place it into the table as a way to demonstrate that things worked.

Using the `init` property within each `.dropzone({})` definition, [as discussed here](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#events), allows me to specify unique `success` and `error` event handlers for each drop zone.

The down side to this approach is there is a lot of code duplicated in order to handle each drop zone; it doesn't scale very well.

### Second solution, a scale-able solution

From the original question, I'm assuming that each drop zone in a table would want to act on the row that contains it upon success thus we need to know which row as part of the success event handler. This proves to be difficult because that information is not exposed in the JavaScript. The `<input type="hidden">` element in each form is used to uniquely identify each form with an `id` value (note, the `id` attribute on the `form` element that was used in the first solution is no longer needed here). The hidden input will automatically be submitted as part of the upload since it's contained within the `<form></form>` elements and I purposely wrote my server side code to return that ID value upon success. Thus I can now get the same results from the first solution, with far less code.

```
$("form.dropzone").dropzone({
  url: $("form").attr("action"),
  previewsContainer: ".dropzone-previews",
  init: function () {
    this.on("success", function (file, response, event) {
      var $preview = $(file.previewElement).find("img");
      var $input = $("table input[value='" + response.id + "']");
      if ($input.length) {
        var $result = $input.closest("tr").find(".js-result");
        $result.html($preview);
      }
    });

    this.on("error", function (file, errorMessage, xhr) {
      console.error("Dropzone Error");
    });
  }
});
```

The `response` variable contains whatever is returned from the server-side script. In my case it's a JSON dictionary like `{ "id": 2 }` and I can access that value with `response.id`.

You could of course pass additional values to the server and back down to allow for additional logic to determine how to handle a successful or failed upload. You could also use completely different URLs for each form which could also effect the result that is passed to the success event handler.

Comment: i love how you explained the solution. is there a possibility to have a clickable button on each row. or use a button to trigger their dropzone select event

Comment: I'm not sure why you're looking for a clickable button on each row but you could use just a `<input type="file" />` to get an upload button on each row. Additionally the area that Drop Zone creates can be clicked to open a browser for file dialog.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My dropzone is a textarea and i want to add a button per row for choose file